# Really Hot Laptop

Tags: hardware-failure, cooling, overheating

My Laptop: Intel 3rd Gen Core i7 2670QM. nVidia GeForce GTX 525. 8GB RAM, 1TB 7200RPM HDD, with Windows 7 Ultimate.

I tend to run a lot of programs, but most are services and Chrome BG processes.

I hardly see my temperature below 80 degrees C. It is usually around 90-95.

I have two questions.

1. Are there easy and cheap hardware modifications to fix this?
2. Will this speed the mechanical/electrical failure of my laptop? My dad noticed that my fan is very loud.

Comment: If the laptop is not new, try cleaning up the fans (use air blower on the fan grill to clear off dust). May consider using those laptop stand with fans underneath to help with the heat dissipation (make sure it is not plastic as they don't dissipate heat as well as a metal or aluminium one). Services and background programs are using up CPU as well so it will heat up. Have you ever checked the temp when nothing is running (just boot up win7, and check average temperature at idle), or is the 90-95 are even when idle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, Laptops will always run hotter than a desktop. This is because there is less room for airflow within a laptop's chassis and less room for larger cooling systems.

With that said, 95 c  is way too high. Perhaps, your temp sensor is giving you the correct reading. Try using a different software to read the temperature. You'd definitely be better off if you could get it down to around 70 c, or even 50 c would be better.

I do not know exactly what you meant by "I have minimum processor state at 0%, max 100%".

- Are you saying that the CPU usage % spikes?

  - If so, how frequently?
  - If not, how much CPU is being used on average?

Since, the description you provided leaves me no way to know how well you've checked the physical condition of the laptop, I can only assume that you (and your dad) have only made a cursory inspection of the problem.

Your first question is not entirely invalid, but it is somewhat premature. There are some other questions we should be asking first, so lets dive into the simplest potential causes, before we get more complicated -- assuming there no obvious software cause...

1. Is the laptop placed on a flat surface with plenty of airflow beneath?

   - *Some laptops 'breath' from the underside. I've had laptops that got really hot -- even powering down -- when I had it on top of a blanket or pillow.*
   - You may also try a laptop surface fan, it will help pull cool air into the machine.
2. When you say that your "dad noticed that my fan is very loud," does that mean the fan is spinning so fast that it makes a lot of noise or does that mean the fan is making a strange (and loud) buzzing noise? Is the fan louder than normal or has it always been loud?

   - Depending on your answer, this could mean a couple things: 1) the fan is running on full speed because the system is trying to prevent overheating, or 2) the fan is wearing out and going bad... it all depends on the type of noise.
3. Have you tried opening up the laptop to make sure there isn't an excessive build-up of
   dust and lint inside?

   - I've had this happen to me before, my laptop was overheating because there was lint clogging up the fan and the pathways for proper airflow.
   - A can of compressed air will make it easier to clean it all out.

These are the easiest things to test for, as long as your CPU isn't maxed out all the time. If the task manager is telling you that you're having huge CPU spikes or even a high, constant CPU usage, then you're probably looking at a software issue.

*However unlikely, you may eventually try re-applying the thermal paste on your CPU to see if that corrects the problem. But I would only go down that road as an option of last resort*

Now, if at this point, you've investigated everything I have described above, then you might want to determine whether it is caused by your operating system or some hardware issue. My personal methodology here tends to lead me towards tinkering and probing my system for clues. As I find clues, I go to google (or superuser.com) for info.

One easy test might be to boot from a linux boot cd, such as a Peppermint OS install cd. Peppermint OS is very lightweight and works well on older systems because it doesn't use a lot of resources. See how it works, surf the net, open some programs... does it get hot? This won't necessarily give you your answer, but it may point you in the right direction. it might suggest the possibility of a hardware issue if it is overheating even when running a lightweight operating system.

If you're running Windows, depending on how old the install is, you may consider reinstalling. But I do understand that this may not be possible if you do not have an install CD.

Of course, these are all things to try, but until you can provide more details there's not much else I can suggest.

Comment: Whoa! Thanks a lot! I was using BatteryCare to read. SpeedFan gives avg. 5 deg lower. That CPU thing was a reference to the "Advanced Power Settings" in Windows: I heard it has to do with Turbo Boost frequency or power. One thing I should mention is that the heat is highly concentrated right above my fan (to the left of the keyboard). Average CPU usage is less than 10%, avg. mem is 5g on Process Explorer and 3g on Task Manager. Smooth desk. No, there was no bad buzzing, etc. from the fan, but it was a loud _fan_ sound, and it did sound _tired_. No. I'm sort of scared to open my laptop.

Comment: I've also used Ubuntu and Fedora on the laptop and it was also subjectively quite hot.

Comment: @SimonKuang what is the make and model of your laptop?

Comment: Dell Inspiron 17R NV7110. A few hours after inadvertently closing YouTube and it's 55 degrees. I think that's the problem ...

Comment: so did you have youtube playing videos non-stop? Perhaps the heat was coming from your graphics card.

Comment: Oh, maybe. I do have graphics card acceleration enabled in YoutubeOptions (3rd party config app).

Comment: I just found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyR1mfzHrQk and guess what is located to the left of the keyboard... the CPU and the other chips, as well as heatsink! And it also looks like the graphics chip is the same region... So, what you described sounds like an over-use of the CPU and/or GPU. Good thing its not some other kind of defect.